# text.box blocked to prevent user answer again but if already answered show the data storage

Tags: c#, textbox, block

I have this in my behind code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    username.Text = "[" + HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name + "]"; 

    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        string sFilePath = Server.MapPath("Database3.accdb");
        OleDbConnection Conn = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + sFilePath + ";Persist Security Info=False;");
        using (Conn)
        {
            Conn.Open();
            OleDbCommand myCommand = new OleDbCommand("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM colaborador WHERE username=@username", Conn);
            myCommand.Parameters.Add("?", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
            int totalRegistos = (int)myCommand.ExecuteScalar();
            if (totalRegistos > 0)
            {
                    // Já registado
                    Label1.Text = "The user already answered before.";
                    business.Enabled = false;
                    business2.Enabled = false;
                    mobile.Enabled = false;
                    Button1.Visible = false;
            }
        }
    }
```

It's possible, in the text.box I get the data saved in the access db?

For example in `mobile.Enabled = false;` appears blocked/deactivate yes but with the data of the database inside.

How can I change my code to do such thing? display what I answered.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a data reader to see if the returned data contains any rows.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    username.Text = "[" + HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name + "]"; 

    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        string sFilePath = Server.MapPath("Database3.accdb");
        OleDbConnection Conn = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + sFilePath + ";Persist Security Info=False;");
        using (Conn)
        {
            Conn.Open();
            OleDbCommand myCommand = new OleDbCommand("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM colaborador WHERE username=@username", Conn);
            myCommand.Parameters.Add("?", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
            OleDbDataReader reader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();

            if (reader.HasRows)
            {
                    // Já registado
                    Label1.Text = "The user already answered before.";
                    business.Enabled = false;
                    business2.Enabled = false;
                    mobile.Enabled = false;
                    mobile.Text = ""; //if this is a textbox
                    Button1.Visible = false;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: ´SqlDataReader reader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();´ @Stephen Brickner the error is: ** Error 1 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataReader' to 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader' **